# API response Status code 400 while calling quickbooks api

Tags: java, jquery, node.js, api, backend

So here is the function where I get the OAUTH2 Token from the Quickbooks server:

```
app.get('/callback', function (req, res) {
    oauthClient
        .createToken(req.url)
        .then(function (authResponse) {
            oauth2_token_json = JSON.stringify(authResponse.getJson(), null, 2);
            console.log("Token:", oauth2_token_json)
            newToken = oauth2_token_json;
            oauthClient.setToken(newToken);
            res.send(newToken);
        })    
});
```

Now, this is where I call the API to push a new Customer but it responds with status code 400. This is a function of Quickbooks library where we call the API directly just by adding the body and a call back function. I've also set the parameters as you can see in the code

```
.then(
                qbo = new QuickBooks('ABReS9hFdUzNlD8Np17ufW8WU5xLyL0M0rv3HvekbXJdZUiWzi',
                            'Uy9NXu2fKmumP3JoCrxKxKugzLkdHhi8Ca00GSBz',
                            `${newToken}`,
                            false, // no token secret for oAuth 2.0
                            '4620816365092507370', // the company name or id provided by Quickbooks
                            true, // use the sandbox?
                            true, // enable debugging?
                            null, // set minorversion, or null for the latest version
                            '2.0', //oAuth version
                            null)
              .createCustomer({
                  "FullyQualifiedName": "King Groceries", 
                  "PrimaryEmailAddr": {
                    "Address": "jdrew@myemail.com"
                  }, 
                  "DisplayName": "King's Groceries", 
                  "Suffix": "Jr", 
                  "Title": "Mr", 
                  "MiddleName": "B", 
                  "Notes": "Here are other details.", 
                  "FamilyName": "King", 
                  "PrimaryPhone": {
                    "FreeFormNumber": "(555) 555-5555"
                  }, 
                  "CompanyName": "King Groceries", 
                  "BillAddr": {
                    "CountrySubDivisionCode": "CA", 
                    "City": "Mountain View", 
                    "PostalCode": "94042", 
                    "Line1": "123 Main Street", 
                    "Country": "USA"
                  }, 
                  "GivenName": "James"
                }, function(err, customer){
                  console.log(customer)
                })
            )
```

When I make the request it hits the correct URL. The ClientID and ClientSecret are completely correct. I don't understand why am I getting this status code. I've changed the sandbox that I was using. I deleted the old sandbox and created a new one. Can anyone explain how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

400 means you sent a request that the server is refusing to process:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

It also says you should not repeat without modifying the request.

What's the problem? Could be a couple of things:

Missing/wrong `Content-Type: ...` header, could be the `Accept: ...` header, or you could be passing invalid data that the server cannot decode.

You need an error message from the server, if you can get one. Perhaps you could also log the error and see if it gives you any more info.

Comment: Sir i called it through that and i set it to "application/json" and it still gave me the same error. I don't know why

Comment: Somewhere the server is returning an error, and you should be able to examine it. You need to do this to get the specifics of the error. Otherwise you are guessing. `.createCustomer` should give you a way to catch the error.